# How to undo "yum remove python"

Tags: centos, python, yum

I have a Centos 6 based VPS with an ssh connection. Recently wanting to install python 2.7.2, I bravely ran:

```
yum remove python
```

which apparently removed yum itself being written or depends on python.

Now I don't know what to do and to make matters worse, I am a complete Linux newbie (command line or otherwise).

Running `rpm -iv http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64.rpm` gives:

```
Retrieving http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
Preparing packages for installation...
        package python-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64 is already installed
```

and its a x86_64 server no question about it as "uname -a" gives:

```
Linux xxxxxx 2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 27 19:49:27 BST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64   GNU/Linux
```

One more thing: `ls /usr/bin/pyth* -la` gives:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    6 Dec  4 20:31 python2 -> python
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4864 Nov 12  2010 python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4864 Nov 12  2010 python;4edbd894
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw the same thing today. Keep Calm and Never run yum erase python: http://www.keepcalmandcarryon.com/creator/?shortcode=qCsMlpyc

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pick a mirror from the list of [CentOS 6 mirrors](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/6/isos/x86_64/) and install the packages you need using `rpm`. You would need to deal with dependencies. Lucky for you, I have a pretty bare VM with CentOS 6 x86_64 installed.

I snapshot the VM, ran `yum remove python` and had some fun getting through some circular dependencies. Final result:

```
# --nodeps: because of circular dependency between python and python-libs
rpm -i --nodeps http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/python-libs-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/pygpgme-0.1-18.20090824bzr68.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/python-iniparse-0.3.1-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -i http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/python-pycurl-7.19.0-5.el6.x86_64.rpm 
rpm -i http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/python-urlgrabber-3.9.1-7.el6.noarch.rpm 
rpm -i http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-python-4.8.0-12.el6.x86_64.rpm 
rpm -i http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-14.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
# --nodeps: because of circular dependency between yum and yum-plugin-fastestmirror
rpm -i --nodeps http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.26-11.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -i http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.2.27-14.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
```

Replace the mirror which whatever one you want. Also, make sure the architecture matches. That should do the trick though!

**Oh one more thing:** If I were you, I'd run a `yum upgrade` right after you're done installing the RPMs.

Comment: That would be great

Comment: After running the first rpm commands, python is being reported as unrecognized command: -bash: python: command not found

Comment: Python will not work till the 2nd RPM file is installed. Hate to be one of "those" but try to understand the command before pasting it. Perhaps a `man rpm` is in order.

Comment: I ran all the first set of 8 commands, that is. The last two are for yum and what you said is obvious. Although running them again gives an 'already installed' message. Perhaps my python directory structure is messed-up or something. And by the way, after installing yum anyway, running yum is giving: "-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Comment: Run `rpm -iv http://centos.mirrors.hoobly.com/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.6.5-3.el6.x86_64.rpm` and paste the output as an edit to your question. Also, are you sure you are running x86_64? Run `uname -a` and paste the output of that in the edit as well please.

Comment: Ok that did the trick, I just renamed "python;4edbd894" to "python" in the "/usr/bin" directory and yum ran normally though I have no idea from where did that name ("python;4edbd894") come from.